# Manifest Merger Failed : Library using cardview 25.3.1 and My app is using 25.00.alpha1

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

I'm getting the error in my gradle console when running the application

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.0-alpha1) from [com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-38
    is also present at [com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-31 value=(25.3.1).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value

"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:41 to override.
```

Can anyone provide me a proper fix for this?

Comment: you have to use same version of support libs. don't use `25.00.alpha1

`

Answer (score 0):

You are using different versions of the Android Support Libraries:

Use like following same version

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

Comment: I want to ignore the one my library is using. I want to use what I have specified in my app gradle. I want to ignore the version of the libraries gradle how can I do that?